# 'rect' attribute missing in Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pygame

I'm trying to make a sprite using pygame, but when I try running the main game loop the error that comes up is

*AttributeError: 'Paddle' object has no attribute 'rect'*

however, to me it looks like I've already used *self.rect = self.paddle.get_rect()* so it should mean that I've already initialized it? Here's the code:

```
import pygame

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init___(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.paddle = pygame.Surface((100, 40))
        self.paddle = self.paddle.convert()
        self.paddle.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.paddle.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 200
        self.rect.top = 400

        self.__screen = screen
        self.__dx = 0

    def change_direction(self, xy_change):
        self.__dx = xy_change[0]

    def update(self):
        if ((self.rect.left > 0) and (self.__dx > 0)) or ((self.rect.left < self.__screen.get_width()) and (self.__dx < 0)):
            self.rect.left -= (self.__dx*5)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In init you have 3 underscores after the word init, so it is never called, there should be 2 either side of the word init (`__init__()`)